# How to select an appropriate class with the same class name in a php while loop

Tags: php, jquery

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
 output .= '<tr>
             <td id=compare><button class=comparison>Search</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id=matching class=matching>
             <td colspan=12>None of a data was found</td>
            </tr>'
}
```

The above shows my php part and the code below shows my jquery process. What I want to do is that when I click on a/any button `class=comparison`, it will shows the hide `tr` which is `class=matching` based on the row of table that have been choose or clicked. But the problem is that when I click on the button, it shows all of the `tr` of the same class.

```
$(".comparison").on("click", function () {
     if($(".matching").is(":hidden")) {
         $(".matching").slideToggle("fast");
     }
     else {
         $(".matching").hide();
     }
});
```

How to select an appropriate class with the same class name in a php while loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you are targeting all elements when using `$(".matching")`. You need to use the relationship between DOM elements and target the desired element.

As per current HTML, you can traverse up to `tr` using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)  then find its immediately following sibling using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".comparison").on("click", function () {
     var matching = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.matching');
     if(matching.is(":hidden")) {
         matching.slideToggle("fast");
     }
     else {
         matching.hide();
     }
});
```

Additionally, **Identifiers in HTML must be unique**, thus get rid of duplicate identifiers since you are not using them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(".matching", $(this))` instead of `$(".matching")` everywhere. The second parameter specifies that you are looking for the matching class inside the current object.

You could also make a variable instead of typing it again and again like this:

```
var matching = $(".matching", $(this))
```

Comment: Since matching is not a child of `button` the above solution will not work

Comment: `$(".matching", $(this))` will internally converted to `$(this).find(".matching")`. Here `this` refers to the `button`which has no child. So in short again it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
$(".comparison").on("click", function () {
   var $matching = $(this).parent().next('.matching');
   if($matching.is(":hidden")) {
     $matching.slideToggle("fast");
   } else {
    $matching.hide();
   }
});
```